# How to connect two Raspberry Pi with OPC UA?

Tags: raspberry-pi, client-server, plc, opc-ua

I have two Raspberry Pi and i want to connect these two via OPC UA making one of them as Server and other as Client. Do you have any Idea or clues or you knows any Websites which helps me to understand the basic ?
Or simply how can i connect Raspberry Pi with PLC machine ?
any small idea can be helpful.
Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 0):

maybe [this](https://www.prosysopc.com/blog/raspberry-pi-demo-updates/) could help, I haven´t tried it but it may be of some help.